# Angular cdkDrag doesn't scroll the container while dragging

Tags: angular, draggable, angular-cdk, angular-cdk-drag-drop

Simplified version here: https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/white-dust-2gldxn

I have a grid container with elements that use cdkDrag directive.
I am intentionally not using cdkDropList in a parent container since I don't want the "side effects" of a list behavior.

What I am trying to do here is to make the container scroll while dragging the cdkDrag elements.

The issue is that the cdkDrag elements don't stick with the mouse pointer but they move up together with the scroll.

I know cdkDropList has this built-in but is there any way to achieve this without using cdkDropList?

Comment: 2 seconds of using google: https://stackblitz.com/edit/cdk-drop-list-scroll?file=main.ts

Comment: @Flo yes but that example uses cdkDropList parent. If you remove that parent, it won't work as expected. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Which side effects you mean?

Comment: @Flo basically, I want to free drag elements on a grid. I got rid of the sorting using cdkDropListSortingDisabled and I am using cdkDragConstrainPosition to simulate a grid like structure.

So, now I got close to achieving what I want using cdkDropList but still not there. Some weird animations going on after releasing the drag. I will update the example in a bit.